# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'catch')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was working on a React app that could perform CRUD operations. I was able to perform Create, Read and Delete but can't seem to get the Update to work. I was following a blog post that was published 2 years ago and I think some of the features that are used on there are no longer available and supported.
I am also getting the following erros.

```
Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
//import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios';
import Sidebar from '../../components/sidebar/Sidebar';
import Navbar  from '../../components/navbar/Navbar';
import "./dbtrial.scss";

export default class DrUpd extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onChangeName= this.onChangeName.bind(this);
    this.onChangeEmail = this.onChangeEmail.bind(this);
    this.onChangePhone = this.onChangePhone.bind(this);
    this.onChangeAddress= this.onChangeAddress.bind(this);
    this.onChangeCountry= this.onChangeCountry.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      address: '',
      country: '',
      driver:[]
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/driver/getDrivers'+this.props.match.params.id)
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        name: response.data.name,
        email: response.data.email,
        phone: response.data.phone,
        address: response.data.address,
        country: response.data.country
      })
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error)
    })  
  }

  onChangeName(e){
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onChangeEmail(e){
    this.setState({
      email: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onChangePhone(e){
    this.setState({
      phone: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onChangeAddress(e){
    this.setState({
      address: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onChangeCountry(e){
    this.setState({
      country: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const driver={
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      phone: this.state.phone,
      address:this.state.address,
      country: this.state.country
    }
    console.log(driver)
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/driver/update/+ this.props.match.params.id', driver )
    .then(res => console.log(res.data));
    
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="db">
            <Sidebar />
            <div className="dbq">
              <Navbar />
              <h3>Edit Driver</h3>
              <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                  <div className="formInput">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text"
                    required
                    
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.onChangeName}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="formInput">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="email"
                    required
                    
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChange={this.onChangeEmail}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="formInput">
                    <label>Phone:</label>
                    <input type="text"
                    required
                    
                    value={this.state.phone}
                    onChange={this.onChangePhone}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="formInput">
                    <label>Address:</label>
                    <input type="text"
                    required
                    
                    value={this.state.address}
                    onChange={this.onChangeAddress}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="formInput">
                    <label>Country:</label>
                    <input type="text"
                    required
                    
                    value={this.state.country}
                    onChange={this.onChangeCountry}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="formInput">
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit Driver"  />
                  </div>
              </form>
            </div>
      </div> 
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The error in your title doesn't match the one in the body of the question.

Comment: `<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>` -> `<form onSubmit={() => this.onSubmit()}>`

Comment: I am getting all the errors at once and I couldn't put them all as a title

Comment: @VLAZ yes that should work, but given the OP is already binding many other methods in the constructor it would be more consistent to just add `this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)` there as well

Comment: after  I added `this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this) ` I can see the new  values in the console but when I refresh the DB the values are not changed and I now get `POST http://localhost:3001/driver/update/ 404 (Not Found) error `